Docker Compose Wordpress Image directory got merge instead of overwritten
My project directory looks like the following
wp-content
 - mu-plugins
 - plugins
 - theme
   - newtheme
docker-compose.yml

and my docker-compose.yml
  # wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content

My question is when I run docker compose up -d
the wp-content directory seems like getting merged I can see my host machine become
wp-content
 - mu-plugins
 - plugins
 - theme
   - newtheme
   - twentytwentyfour
   - twentytwentythree
docker-compose.yml

Why is that? I was hoping the both the container and my host machine have my original project directory instead
wp-content
 - mu-plugins
 - plugins
 - theme
   - newtheme
docker-compose.yml

How can I fix this?
